# my adapter not been initialized, how to initialized it, i trying many times but always error

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter, searchview

My adapter not been initialized, how to initialized it, i trying many times but always error.
this is my logcat when i am running my app
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property adapter has not been initialized

I want my searchview work properly but my app always crash when clik the searchview

this is my code

```kotlin
class GlosaryFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var preferences: Preferences
    private lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference
    private var datalist = ArrayList<Istilah>()
    private lateinit var adapter: DaftarIstilahAdapter

    private var _binding: FragmentGlosaryBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentGlosaryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        preferences = Preferences(requireActivity().applicationContext)
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Istilah")



        binding.tvName.text = preferences.getValues("nama")
        binding.tvSchool.text = preferences.getValues("sekolah")

        Glide.with(this)
            .load(preferences.getValues("url"))
            .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
            .into(binding.ivAvatar)

        binding.rvDaftarIstilah.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        getData()

        binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object  : androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
                searchList(newText)
                return true

            }

        })

    }

    fun searchList(text: String){
        val searchList = kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Istilah>()
        for (dataclass in datalist){
            if (dataclass.istilah!!.lowercase().contains(text.lowercase())){
                searchList.add(dataclass)
            }
        }
        adapter.searcDataList(searchList)

    }

    private fun getData() {
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                datalist.clear()
                for (getSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    var istilah = getSnapshot.getValue(Istilah::class.java)
                    datalist.add(istilah!!)
                }

                binding.rvDaftarIstilah.adapter = DaftarIstilahAdapter(datalist) {
                    var intent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java).putExtra("data",it)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "" + error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        })

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

}
```

my adapter

```kotlin
class DaftarIstilahAdapter(
    private var data: ArrayList<Istilah>,
    private val listener: (Istilah) -> Unit
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DaftarIstilahAdapter.ViewHolder>(){


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            GlosaryDetailBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context
                ), parent,false)
        )

    }

    override fun getItemCount() = data.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val data = data[position]
        holder.binding.tvIstilah.text = data.istilah
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
            listener(data)
        }
        

    }

    fun searcDataList(searchList :ArrayList<Istilah>){
        data = searchList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }




    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: GlosaryDetailBinding)
        :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)



}
```

I want my searchview work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using lateinit for your adapter

```
private lateinit var adapter: DaftarIstilahAdapter
```

initialise your adapter in on create -

and remove parameters from constructor of DaftarIstilahAdapter

so that you can make its object only once in onCreate

it will be like this

```
class DaftarIstilahAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<DaftarIstilahAdapter.ViewHolder>()
```

and make functions in your DaftarIstilahAdapter class for setting data and setting listeners

```
private var mData = ArrayList<Istilah>()
private fun setData(data: ArrayList<Istilah>){ this.mData = data }

private var listener: ((Istilah) -> Unit)? = null
private fun setListener(listener: (Istilah)->Unit) { this.listener = listener }
```

and use `binding.rvDaftarIstilah.adapter = adapter` in on create make sure you initialise adapter before using it

```
adapter = DaftarIstilahAdapter()
```

and your getData function will be like this

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            datalist.clear()
            for (getSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                var istilah = getSnapshot.getValue(Istilah::class.java)
                datalist.add(istilah!!)
            }
           adapter.setData(datalist)

        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "" + error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    })
```

also in onCreate set listener for your adapter like:

```
adapter.setListener{ //do your work here }
```